# $\frac{ \sin\theta }{ \theta } = \frac{2165}{2166}$ Find the approximate value of $\theta$

Tags: trigonometry, taylor-expansion

> $\dfrac{ \sin\theta }{ \theta }$ = $\dfrac{2165}{2166}$
>   Find the approximate value of $\theta$

What is the method to solve this question. (I have tried solving it by using Taylor series expansion, but didn't got answer.

Comment: You claim to have used Taylor series, but you have not shown what you tried.  Without knowing what you tried, it is difficult to know where you encountered an issue.  The solution is quite straightforward and I have difficulty believing that you could know to use a series expansion yet fail to compute a suitable approximation.

Comment: Sorry sir, I used Taylor series for only numerator part, this is where the problem occurred.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\sin x/x \approx 1-x^2/6$
so $x^2/6 \approx 1/2166$
so $x^2 \approx 6/2166
= 1/361$
so $x \approx 1/19$.

Answer (score 2):

The solution of
$$\dfrac{ \sin(\theta) }{ \theta }=\dfrac{2165}{2166}=1-\dfrac{1}{2166}$$ must be very close to $\theta=0$. So, using Taylor expansion is a good idea; with the standard series of $\sin(\theta)$ we then have
$$\dfrac{ \sin(\theta) }{ \theta }=1-\frac{\theta^2}{6}+\frac{\theta^4}{120}+O\left(\theta^6\right)$$ So, ignoring the higher order terms, you can solve either
$$-\frac{\theta^2}{6}=-\dfrac{1}{2166}\implies \theta= ???$$ or, if you want more accuracy, solve
$$-\frac{\theta^2}{6}+\frac{\theta^4}{120}=-\dfrac{1}{2166}\implies \theta= ???$$ This last is just a quadratic in $\theta^2$.

**Edit**

Sooner or later, you will learn that, better than with Taylor series, we can approximate functions using [Padé approximants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pad%C3%A9_approximant). For example, the simplest one would be
$$\dfrac{ \sin(\theta) }{ \theta }=\frac{60-7 \theta^2}{60+3 \theta^2}$$ and then, you just need to solve for  $\theta^2$
$$\frac{60-7 \theta^2}{60+3 \theta^2}=\dfrac{2165}{2166}$$ which is simpler than the quadratic and at least as accurate.

Comment: Since both terms are close to 1, taking one minus each results in a simpler equation.

Comment: Also, as shown by my solution, the problem was clearly designed to use the Taylor series.

Comment: @martycohen. For sure, it was ! When I saw the rhs so close to $1$, then .... Cheers :-)